# Rails using a background process app call back to trigger an event

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have an app which uses the SuckerPunch gem and Carrierwave Backgrounder to upload and process images in the background of a rails application. So when a user creates an instance of the Asset model, while the image is processing, there is an attribute `attachment_processing?` in the Asset model which is set to true. I indicate this to the user using this view template

```
-if instance.send(base_name)
  .form-row
    - if instance.send(base_name).attachment_processing?
      .image_processing
        %span Processing Asset #{proccessing_asset_name(instance.send(base_name))}
        = image_tag("ajax-loader.gif")
    - else    
       = nice_asset(instance.send(base_name),options[:thumb])
```

When the asset has finished processing the attribute is set to false and the image displays AFTER a page refresh. Looking at the server logs, this automatically kicks in when it has finished processing.

```
Started GET "/assets/ajax-loader.gif" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-21 16:10:38 +0000
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE `assets` SET `attachment_processing` = 0, `updated_at` = '2014-11-21 16:11:14' WHERE `assets`.`id` = 6362
   (1.9ms)  COMMIT
```

Is there a way, via ajax or some other method, to use this to automatically display the finished image?
I am just looking for a more user friendly approach, instead of asking the user to refresh the page or something like that?

Many thanks

Comment: Yah, I would suggest you to go for websocket! socket.io can solve that with the help of redis pubsub.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to set the page to [auto refresh](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp) every few seconds, this will make the page fully refresh whether there was an update or not:

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
</head>
```

If you want a bit more finesse, you might want to poll the server using [ajax](http://rustudy.blogspot.co.il/2012/07/replacement-for-periodicallycallremote.html), and refresh the page (or the relevant part of the page) using javascript when needed:

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(updateSeats,30000);
 });
  function updateSeats(){
    $.ajax({
    url:  "/flights/<%= @flight.id %>/seats",
    type: "GET",
  }).done(function(data){
    $("#seats").html(data);
  });
  }
</script>
```

You could also consider implementing more elaborate push-like schemes like [long polling](http://jordanhollinger.com/2011/05/15/writing-an-ajax-long-polling-server-in-ruby-part-1/), according to the use-case at hand.

Comment: he seems to be asking for event driven solution!

Comment: @Rubyrider - he wants an event driven solution between the server and client. Since a web server cannot send push messages to a client, a polling solution needs to be implemented to simulate it... it can be as crude as refreshing the page periodically, or as elaborate as a long polling implementation

Comment: yah implementation would be complex for this use case.